# Boruta feature selection with R

Tags: r, machine-learning, boruta

I used Boruta algorithm in R on a data set of ~600 attributes  and with a sample of 50K (the original size is 300K).

Using the following parametres:

- pValue = 0.05
- getImp = getImpRfZ
- maxRuns = 11

After it finishes all my attributes stand on "Tentative". None variable is refused or accepted.

I have already tried with less sample and 300 variables (to do not waste time) but I get the same.

Now is runnung with pValue = 0.20, in order to let the variables pass through...

Anybody has an assumption of this? It would be very nice some help here... I was betting to get quiet the same **GINI** removing variables from Boruta´s help.

---

Just for inform!

After being quiet patient I could increase the number of maxRuns to 50... And I could reduce 60% of the variables which is really nice obtaining the same result! I changed the pValue parameter but did not change anything

Answer (score 1):

Tentative basically means "too little iterations to decide", so increasing `maxRuns` is a way to go in this case; honestly lowering this parameter below 100 is almost always a bad idea. In case computational time is a concern, it is better to change the importance source.

`pValue` is used for an internal binomial test, hence changing it less than by an order of magnitude is not going to change much, and setting it to something larger than 0.01 is basically asking for a random, nonsense result. Anyway, it only exists for crazy experiments and, as the documentation states, 
*Default value should be used.*